# What is the closest thing to Apache Hadoop in other languages?

Tags: c++, python, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

Specifically any Open Source implementations at any degree of usefulness in the following languages:

1) C++

2) Python

3) Ruby

4) C#

Comment: Note that Hadoop, while being written in Java, does not force you to write your code in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The german wikipedia has some software examples for each language. I'm translating:

- Apache Hadoop MapReduce (natively Java, pipes to C++, Python, etc.)
- disco Open Source Project (Python and Erlang) by Nokia Research Center
- Greenplum MapReduce by Greenplum (not sure, seems to be C++ though, but with a SQL layer like PIG/Hive).
- QtConcurrent Open Source C++ MapReduce implementation (but not distributed) by Qt Software
- Skynet Ruby Map/Reduce Framework
- Plasma MapReduce (Ocaml) with its own distributed filesystem called
  "PlasmaFS"

[Source](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Software)

Answer (score 2):

For Python there is Disco from Nokia: http://discoproject.org/

Comment: +1 for disco, it is a fairly complete stack for distributed computing and map/reduce including a distributed fs